# onClick in FlipView library

Tags: android, onclick, flipview

I am currently integrating the FlipView library (https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView) in my Android app. I absolutely need to enable onClick, but it doesn't work the way it worked with ListView. I know I will need to adapt FlipView, but I don't really know how.

This is the code I've been using so far to handle onClick events:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(FlipView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (id >= 0) { // should not happen, but I had a crash with this on PlayStore...
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ContentUris.withAppendedId(mUri, id)));
    }
}
```

Could someone help me? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: There is no crash at all, nothing happens at all.. I've found an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not implement a viewHolder in the adapter and get the roo element and set the onclick listener to that?

Comment: This is what I figured out around half a year ago. Thanks though for other people that may read this!

Comment: @FlorentAnders By the way, are you experiencing any performance hit when you use that library? It takes a moment to load when I use it.

Comment: No, it has always loaded well for me. You can check out my implementation if you want, com.fa.daily.app on the Play Store